# How many 4 digit numbers in the octal number system exist such that they are formed using exactly three distinct digits?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

My approach :

I divided it into 2 cases firstly :Case 1) the numbers having no 0s  and  Case 2)the numbers having a 0 in them

so **Case 1 :**

choosing 3 digits out of 7 in 7c3 ways = 35 ways

now arranging the 4 digits in 4!/(2!) ways

therefore number of ways = 35 * 12 = 420

Now **Case 2 :**

Here we have selected one 0 , now remaining 2 digits can be chosen in 7c2 ways =21 ways

now arranging the 4 numbers we get ( 4!/2!) - 3! = 6 ways

giving total of 126 numbers

therefore my answer is coming out to be 420 + 126 = 546 numbers

But the answer is given as 1764 numbers, Can someone guide me on where am I going wrong , and how to correct

Comment: You skipped choosing which of the $3$ digits is repeated.  That increases your options threefold.

Comment: yes I had skipped that part, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1

"choosing 3 digits out of 7 in 7c3 ways = 35 ways"

> choosing which of the 3 digits is repeated give as $35\cdot 3 = 105$ ways to have four digits where exactly three are unique.

"now arranging the 4 digits in 4!/(2!) ways"

"therefore number of ways = $\require{cancel}$$\cancel{35}105 * 12 = \cancel{420}1260$"

Case 2a

"Here we have selected one 0 , now remaining 2 digits can be chosen in 7c2 ways =21 ways"

> Choosing which number is repeated.  Case 2a: there are $21\cdot 1 = 21$ ways the $0$ is repeated.  Case 2b: there are $21\cdot 2 = 42$ ways a number other than the $0$ is repeated.

now arranging the 4 numbers we get ( 4!/2!)= 12 ways but we must subtract the ones where a $0$ is in the first digit.

Case 2a: the first non-zero has $3$ choices of positions and the second has $2$ choices of position so there are $6$ positions where $0$ is in the first position. [We can verify that $00ab, 00ba, 0a0b, 0b0a, 0ab0, 0ba0$].  So there are $12-6 = 6$ ways.

Case 2b: There are ${3\choose 2}= 3$ ways to choose the positions for the $2$ repeating digits in three positions  [$0aab, 0aba, 0baa$].  So there are $12-3 = 9$ ways.

So 2a:  $21\times 6 = 126$.  ANd $2b = 42\times 9 = 378$.

So $1260 + 126 + 378 = 1764$

Answer (score 2):

A neat way of solving *without cases*, using probability, is to first compute including leading $0's$ and multiply by $\frac78$ to exclude them.

Thus $\binom42\cdot 8\cdot7\cdot6\times\frac78 = 1764$

Comment: can you elaborate your solution a bit please, I didn't get why you multiplied the total cases with 7/8

Comment: Initially, we allowed $0's$ as a leading digit, which needs to be corrected for. By symmetry, $0$ will be a leading digit in $\frac18$ of the combos, so $\frac78$ will not have a leading $0$, that is why this factor.

Comment: if possible could you show how you applied symmetry here to get 1/8 ? Is it like in if I write 8 combos , there would be 1 combo with 0 in front ? I am not getting it very clearly , please can you help me out with the symmetry part

Comment: The octal system has $8$ numbers, viz $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. When you look at the leading digit,  each of these $8$ numbers are equally likely, so $0$ will occur $1/8$ of the time.

Comment: but if I have a number of the form aabc, then I get that probability of a=0 in front would be 3!/12 = 1/2 ?

Comment: We don't consider one possible sequence for the probability, we consider **all** possible sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1 (no zeros): Suppose you have chosen three digits, say, $\{1,2,5\}$. Choose one of them to appear twice ($3$ choices). Then choose the two places where it appears, $\binom{4}{2}=6$ choices. Then choose which way the remaining two digits fill the remaining two places, $2$ choices. You should have $3 \times 6 \times 2 = 36$ choices, not 12. (You seem to have forgotten the choice of which digit appears twice.)

You might have a similar mistake in case 2. Check it out.